# Continue the script from the same point where the error was thrown

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, screen-scraping

Hello Friends what i want to accomplish is that i want to traverse through pages by clicking the next button but however when i get any error the script stops and i need to rerun the script from where it had stopped basically it should continue fromt the next page after the page it stopped..
follwing codetraverses and also stores the current page number can you help me to proceed further.

```
def next():
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[8]/div/span/div/div/ul/li[9]/a')
    browser.implicitly_wait(10)
    ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(button).click(button).perform()



for i in range(1,399):
        CurentPage_num = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[8]/div/span/div/div/ul/li[@class="a-selected"]')
        for ij in CurentPage_num:
            jq = ij.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
            print(jq)
        next()
```

The above code is for the url : https://www.amazon.com/s?i=toys-and-games-intl-ship&bbn=16225015011&rh=n%3A16225015011%2Cn%3A166092011&qid=1578647211&ref=sr_pg_1

Comment: add code with try-except if any exception generates then pass it.

Comment: Where you are getting exceptions?and this xpath is not present on the page `//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[8]/div/span/div/div/ul/li[9]/a`

Comment: @KunduK the correct path is '//*[@class="a-pagination"]/li[@class="a-last"]/a' and also it is not the exception i am worried about i can catch it but however i want that whenever the browser closes it should take the page number last stored and run next func till that page and then again continue  the working of the script from the next page